# Viewpager gets the wrong page

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-adapter

I have looked in several topics like this but didn't see how to fix my problem

I have a resturant for say.. with dynamic number of categories.. I put all the categories in a list.. and create fragments by from those categories

so I cant just

case 0 : fragment0
case 1 :frament 1

because I dont know how much categories I have untill runtime

```
class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private List<MyFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
private List<menuCat> Categories = new ArrayList<>();

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<menuCat> Categories) {
    super(fm);
    this.Categories = Categories;
    for (int i = 0; i<Categories.size();i++)
    {
        fragments.add(MyFragment.newInstance(Categories.get(i)));
    }
}

@Override
public String getPageTitle(int position)
{
    return Categories.get(position).catName();
}

@Override
public MyFragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

MyFragment.class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

public static final MyFragment newInstance(menuCat category)
{
    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
    bun.putString("category", category.toJson());
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    f.setArguments(bun);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
    String json = getArguments().getString("category");
    menuCat category = menuCat.fromJson(json);

    System.out.println(category.catName());

    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

   for(menuItem item : category.getItems())
   {
       Card card = new Card(getActivity());
       // Create a CardHeader
       CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getActivity());
       // Add Header to card
       header.setTitle(item.getName());
       card.setTitle(item.getPrice());
       card.addCardHeader(header);

       CardThumbnail thumb = new CardThumbnail(getActivity());
       //thumb.setDrawableResource(listImages[i]);
       //card.addCardThumbnail(thumb);

       cards.add(card);
   }


    CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getActivity(), cards);

    CardListView listView = (CardListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myList);
    if (listView != null) {
        listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
    }
    return v;

}
```

}

this is my adapter, my problem is for example

if I am in page 1 and I need page 3 data.. if I will go to page 2.. it will display data of page 3 OR if I go to page 5 then go backward.. to 4 it  will also show data of page 3.. I mean it gets me like the data of the next page instead of current one.

Answer (score 0):

Creating all of your fragments in the constructor is very poor design, as you're creating references to these objects which will later be attached to an `Activity`, but when they are detached, you continue to hold the reference. In the end, this is going to cause you a lot of frustration with memory leaks.

Is it not possible to simply remove `fragments` and change your methods to the following:

```
@Override
public MyFragment getItem(int position) {
    return MyFragment.newInstance(Categories.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Categories.size();
}
```

I'm not certain this will solve all of your problems, but it is a start.

Comment: it didnt solve my problem.. my constructor looked like this because I tried many different ways to make it work.. still no solution. but thanks for the advice

Comment: any more solutions please?